# Photoshop: Switch left and right in dual monitor setup

Tags: display, adobe-photoshop, multiple-monitors

(Important note:  I am looking for a solution that does not affect any other applications.  Swapping cables or changing my desktop settings is not what I'm looking for.)

---

I have dual monitors and **in Photoshop** I have my main document view on the left and toolbars / palettes on the right.  I'm on a Windows machine.

Is there an easy way -- within Photoshop -- to switch my setup so that everything that was on the left monitor goes to the right and vice versa?

Comment: (Argh, why was this migrated to Superuser?  In my mind, this is an application-specific question that Photoshop users would be more likely to know the answer to.  I may flag this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *easy* way but still *a* way I did was

- to store 2 displayconfigs. In my
  scenario I had a Nvidia card with two
  monitors. I used the nview (or
  something) utility that got activated
  through after connecting the second
  monitor. I created two profiles where
  the main monitor was in one case the
  right one and on the other the left
  one. I had to restart photoshop
  though to get the changes.
- The other solution I remember was to
  save two separate workspaces in photoshop having a normal and an inverted one.

I don't remember the details.. specially how useful this really got. After a time I recall making the effort to leave the workspaces as they were (ie ONE way only) and got around to using one monitor predominantly and the other as secondary.

this helped me to organize the windows more efficently since I lost less time searching on which monitor were which windows and also spend less time resizing and moving them around. In a way this sounds contradictory to having two monitors setup. For me it got easier. In the end that matters more than using the "full potential" of this setup.

(I'm now back to just one BIG monitor and miss a second one desperately)
I hope this helped you out

Comment: The Workspace was a promising idea, but when I tried it, Photoshop would only remember the palettes, but not the main document window.  I don't know if this is a feature or a bug =(  +1 anyways, as it gets me *most* of the way there!

Answer (score 0):

[I don't know if this works, but it should]

Use windows' built in monitor controller (XP and Vista: control panel>display or right click on the desktop and choose display or properties, 7: control panel > screen resolution or right click on the desktop and choose screen resolution), and just swap the positions of the monitors.

Comment: Though this affects all the other applications as well, which was an unwanted effect.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy way to do it on Linux and Windows. First open the settings for displays

- **Linux:** Settings -> Display
- **Windows:** Control Panel -> Screen Resolution (or right click on the desktop and choose screen resolution is you have anything above Home Premium)

Then, just swap the positions of the monitors by dragging one to the other side of the other monitor and wallah!, the windows on the monitors have now changed position.

This also has the unintended (and probably unwanted) side-effect of affecting *all* windows as opposed to just the PhotoShop ones, but I don't know of any way to stop that.

Comment: You didn't read the very first sentence of my question: *"I am looking for a solution that does not affect any other applications."*

Comment: @anon Sorry -_- Oh well, at least my answer could be of some help to other users who stumble upon this question.